# implement some methods of interface explicitly and some methods implicitly

Tags: c#

can i implement some methods of an interface explicitly and some methods implicityly in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as long the compiler can resolve all the methods, there's no issue with mixing.  I do this every once in a while just because I have to explicitly implement something it can't resolve for some edge case, but the implicit members continue to work just fine.

Comment: will the explicit methods accessible by class instance?

Comment: yes they will, but you will have to cast the instance to that particular interface.

Comment: @user283405 - Steven's correct, they're not accessible directly, in that case an implicit interface seems what you want, with a cast you can get the members though.